# 404 Error even though file exist (asp) just when publish not local host

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with the name "man.aspx" , when i open it , it works good in localhost,
but when i publish it , it give error :

```
mywebsite-3.ir/error.htm?aspxerrorpath=/man.aspx
```

or

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Comment: I've got the same problem! It worked fine before but now, seems like the server can't find my Default.aspx though it exists.

Answer (score 0):

It can be cause by a lot of things, did you set the path properly in IIS ?

Does you default page is displayed correctly ? Try to add a file with index.html in your root folder.

Did you set ASP.Net ?

Go into IIS Manager -> Servername -> "Web Service Extensions", and set ASP.NET v2.0.xxxxxx to Allowed.

Comment: All of my page works correctly , but just this page "man.aspx" give error.